# Scatter plot of 2 variables with colorbar based on third variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, colorbar

I am trying to plot with variable x with respect to another y and add a colormap based on the values of another variable z

So the plot should be similar to this

[image: Plots]

My try

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

x=np.random.randint(0,20,30)
y=np.random.randint(-5,5,30)
z=np.random.randint(-2,10,30)
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'A':x,'B':y,'C':z})

points = plt.scatter(df['A'],df['B'],cmap="jet")
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
m.set_array(df['C'])
plt.colorbar(points)
sns.lmplot('A', 'B', data=df, hue='C', fit_reg=False)

TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable
```

I am mixing matplotlib and seaborn as in seaborn I can not use the colormap 'jet'
But any alternative aproaches to get the same graph are welcome

Answer (score 10):

How about this (use c=df.C in the scatter command):

```
points = plt.scatter(df.A, df.B, c=df.C,cmap="jet", lw=0)
plt.colorbar(points)
```

[image]