# How to specify scatter plot point color in matplotlib pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset with a million of points like:

```
1.0,9.5,-0.3
2.3,4.8,0.7
8.1,3.6,0.0
3.9,1.4,-0.1
4.7,5.3,0.0
```

and PyPlot code like

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

headers =  ['A','B','C']
df = pandas.read_csv('my_data.csv',names=headers)
df['x'] = df['A']
df['y'] = df['B']
# df['color'] = df['C']
plt.xlim(min(df['x'])/2, max(df['x'])*2)
plt.ylim(min(df['y'])/2, max(df['y'])*2)
plt.xlabel("A")
plt.ylabel("B")
plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], 'o', ms = 0.2) 
plt.show()
```

I can plot points according to first and second column, but all points have the same color. How to tell PyPlot to color points based on the value in third column?

Comment: c = df['color']

Comment: also, i'm not clear why you're adding df columns - you could just plt.scatter(df['A'], df['B'], c = df['C'])

Comment: @mauve how to convert 'C' that is double in range -2.0 .. 3.0 to nicely spaced 256 colors? Should I write ` c = double_to_color(df['C'])`? What should be in the function? A  switch with 256 cases `if value less then, but more than`?

Comment: if you do c = df['C'], it will automatically coordinate the color range with your value range.

Comment: `plt.plot` can only ever have a single color. Did you mean to use `plt.scatter` instead?

Comment: See the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50527658/scatter-plot-of-2-variables-with-colorbar-based-on-third-variable

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use plt.scatter() instead of plt.plot(). There's also no need to re-name the DataFrame columns, the first argument is the x values and the second is the y values. c = z will make the colors be determined by whatever the z values are. cmap will determine what the colors are. [Here are the options](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) plt.colorbar() will give you a colorbar reference for the colors plotted for z.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


x = [random.randint(0,100) for x in range(1000)]
y = [random.randint(0,100) for y in range(1000)]
z = [random.randint(0,100) for z in range(1000)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': x, 'B':y, 'C':z})

plt.scatter(df['A'], df['B'], c = df['C'], cmap = 'rainbow')
plt.colorbar()    
plt.show()
```

Comment: Rainbow worked like a charm.

Comment: @Stepan: You can also use `x = np.random.randint(0,100,1000)` from Numpy

Answer (score 1):

In your case changing

```
plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], 'o', ms = 0.2)
```

to

```
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], 'o',c = df['color'], ms = 0.2)
```

should work, assuming that `df['color']` is the same length as the `x` and `y` variables.

As was pointed out in the comments, there is no (apparent) need to create new `df` columns.

This you could use this

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

headers =  ['A','B','C']
df = pandas.read_csv('my_data.csv',names=headers)

plt.xlim(min(df['A'])/2, max(df['A'])*2)
plt.ylim(min(df['B'])/2, max(df['B'])*2)
plt.xlabel("A")
plt.ylabel("B")
plt.scatter(df['A'], df['B'], 'o', c = df['C'], ms = 0.2) 
plt.show()
```

*Edit:*

If you really want to make sure that each point has a unique color, then you need to make sure that the `c` input also only contains unique values.

```
c = [i for i in range(0,len(df['C'])]
plt.plot(df['A'], df['B'], 'o', c = c, ms = 0.2)
```

Comment: My `'C'` column contain doubles. How to convert it to colors?

Comment: what do you mean "doubles"

Comment: variable type. Like `0.123`, `-4.567`, not like `True` and not like `"blue"`

Comment: again, that is solved by c = z, it's a feature in matplotlib.

Comment: @Stepan added in an edit